# Searching and printing in linux

Tags: playonlinux

Question:- Write a grep command that prints out all the lines containing the word 'Good'.

There are 42000 lines in an Excel file and I want to find and print the line that contains the word 'Good' under section 'C' only.
But the word 'Good' can appear under the 'D' section as well si it prints the wrong lines as well which I don't want to see.

I need a little help with the code.

Link to the image :  https://i.stack.imgur.com/3WJrP.png

Comment: Which format does the file you are using grep on have? Is it a CSV file?

Comment: Don't "write a grep command" for this - for simple columnar data you can use awk, otherwise use a tool that parses CSV properly such as Miller, Perl (with the Text::CSV module) or python (if you don't want to roll your own, you could use `csvsql` from the python-based `csvkit` - although its overkill for such a simple query)

Comment: Yes it is a CSV file danzel